# Почему окрашивается второй элемент с таким же id?

Tags: html, css

Я поставил один и тот же `id` для двух элементов. Почему второй окрашивается?

```css
#red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="red"> red </span> no red <span id="red"> red </span>
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262195/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что это css. Теоретически, каждый элемент проверяется на соответствие каждому селектору. В данном случае обоим элементам селектор подошёл.

В отличие от js, где по запросу выдаётся один элемент, в css стили применяются к имеющимся элементам, а не отслеживается, к скольки элементам может быть применён этот селектор с необходимостью последующего слежения за появлением таких элементов.

Ну и да, разметка всё равно невалидна.

Comment: тут `js`, наверное, следует заменить на `DOM`.

Comment: @teran, не понял, как именно.

Comment: уникальность селектора определяется на уровне [`HTML DOM`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), а `js` лишь может работать с моделью документа и по сути не имеет требований  к уникальности идентификаторов. То есть сам по себе `js` то тут ни при чем вообще. При этом уникальность нужна не во всем документе, а в ветке дерева.

Comment: @teran, вообще, у меня идея ответа была, что в css для каждого элемента проверяются селекторы, а в js для селектора выбираются соответствующие ему элементы. Кстати, хром мне сейчас на querySelectorAll('#red') выдал все, хотя в jQuery такое раньше точно не прокатывало...

Comment: да, идею я вашу понял. Просто выходит что есть HTML, который накладывает сами ограничения на уникальность и формируют документ. И есть два инструмента - `css`, применяющий правила визуального оформления, и `js`, позволяющий манипулировать структурой. Поэтому говорить о `css` и `js`,  не затрагивая HTML, как-то не совсем корректно.

Comment: @teran, но html один и тот же - он как бы неявно подразумевается.

Answer (score 4):

В случае с CSS id ведёт себя как класс, но в JavaScript будет применяться только к первому элементу:

```js
document.getElementById("red").style.color = "red";
```

```html
<span id="red"> red </span> no red <span id="red"> red </span>
```

Comment: Эм.. Это ответ?

Comment: @Qwertiy а что такое?

Comment: @Qwertiy ваш ответ, в общем-то, не шибко информативней

Comment: @teran, я пытался ответить на вопрос "почему". А тут я вижу только какой-то странный факт :)